# Cassandra: How to insert row without name

Tags: cassandra

I need to do some cassandra for study project.

It's really simple:

One Column Family, two colums (let's say 'name' and 'mail')

Now I wanna insert some data to Cassandra like

'name' => 'Horst',
'mail' => 'Horst@Horstweb.com'

Don't need nothing more - but cassandra needs an sub name for the column family.

columnFamilyName.ABC (
 ...
)

Is there a way to insert data without this ABC? I only need the columns - nothing more.

Thank's allot for your help.

Pascal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Row keys are required and they must be unique -- think of them like primary keys in an RDBMS.  If you don't care what they are and you just need them to be unique, you would normally use a UUID.  But since you only have two rows, why not just name them 'a' and 'b'?

Comment: Oh, I'm sory! I meant "columns" - not "rows".

Comment: Ah, okay, that's a different question.  @DNA explains some of this in his answer, but you could just store the data as the column name and use an empty column value.

Answer (score 1):

No, you must always have a row name (key). Pretty much anything will do if you just need a dummy row key:

```
row1 -> name    mail
        Horst   Horst@Horstweb.com
```

Or, in principle, you could use row keys instead of column names:

```
name -> value
        Horst

mail -> value
        Horst@Horstweb.com
```

or even:

```
name -> Horst
        []

mail -> Horst@Horstweb.com
        []
```

Where `[]` indicates an empty value (Cassandra column values can be left empty).

This is just using Cassandra as a simple hashtable i.e. wasting most of Cassandra's column-store capabilities!